# Do farmers gain any particular benefits from crop monitoring?

Tags: remote-sensing, agriculture, machine-learning

Recently, crop monitoring through satellite or other remote sensing devices has become a hot topic. However, I was wondering if, say, satellite data combined with ML software mapping out crops being grown in different parts of the map of the region would really be of use to a farmer since it seems that the farmer would obviously already know these things beforehand. What exactly is the information gained by the farmer, especially if the farmer is engaging in intensive farming, from crop monitoring through remote sensing and AI combination that the farmer already didn't know?

Comment: John Deere Precision  Agriculture is a good source for any specific questions you have.

Comment: Is your question specifically about ML/AI?  There are many other ways to derive value from data that do not involve ML/AI.

Comment: @gerrit yes, for now, let's just be specific to ML/AI applications to agriculture.

Comment: What makes you think the farmer would already know their crop conditions? do you think you just stick seeds in the ground and walk away for a few months?

Comment: @John my apologies for not clarifying the question enough; however, by the term "crop monitoring" I am specifically referring to satellite images being used to map out crops being grown in different areas of the region. More specifically, I am referring to the work done in [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8999620).

I understand that things such as disease detection, weed growth etc would be greatly helpful to the farmer; however, this is not the work that was done in the above paper.

Comment: You do realize satellite images can be used ot detect disease, weeds, crop health, moisture, ect. the paper is about a new way to process data not about a particular application. You should really familiarize yourself with modern farming practices.